# Ruby String variable returning true for .is_a?(Array)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a method that will either get an array or a string

For the method to work correctly, I need to convert that string to an array.
Since it will sometimes get string, I wanted to have it check if the variable is an array, and if not convert it to an array. So I did the following:

```
unless variablename.is_a?(Array)
  variablename = variablename.lines.to_a
end
```

The second line of this fails and I get a ruby error that 'lines' is not available to an array object.

I also tried .kind_of? with same results

I got my answer but I also wanted to clear up what exactly I was asking.
I am testing to see if variablename is an array. For some reason when variablename is an array, it still runs and than the second line fails with the following error:
        undefined method `lines' for #Array:0x000000021382b8 (NoMethodError)

Comment: Can you inspect `variablename` to ensure its contents and type, and provide the actual exception thrown?

Comment: Seems like `variablename` is not a string either. However, why don't you just pass `string.lines` to your method instead of `string` and avoid the check?

Comment: Why check at all?  `Array#to_a` just returns itself, no need to check.

Comment: @NickVeys `String#to_a` is not defined.

Comment: @Stefan I wanted to put this in the method, so the method would work regardless of what was sent to it. This method is called many times throughout the script. I could easily do that, I was hoping to find a solution inside the method.

Comment: If the two answers given are not correct, then you need to improve the Question since it is thus unclear what you need.

Comment: What is the purpose of `to_a`? Whenever `String#lines` succeeds, isn't the result an array?

Comment: What happens if you insert `p variablename.class` right after the condition? What will it say?

Comment: Would be interesting to see and try the whole failing program. Could you gist or pastie it?

Comment: Looking at your error message, it doesn't look like you have an array. maybe you have something related to it, such as singleton class of Array or something. What does `p variablename.class` say?

Comment: In 2 different places in the script, it correctly lists "string" and "Array". I need to get my box where it needs to be so I can reproduce this with actual data instead of test data to verify. It is working with the test data but didn't work previously.

Comment: @JonHeckman Unless you can show us the code or follow the really simple debugging instructions by sawa, we aren't gonna get anywhere.

Comment: I got it working. Sorta. doing p variablename.class told me what I needed. The problem was an assumption I made that I apparently can't without heavy modification to the rest of the program (I assumed everywhere that called this method was built to handle an array and it couldn't). So the .lines error was on the return from this method not inside this method. Thanks for everyone helping through, even through the block itself was working, the steps here helped me find the actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def do_stuff(x)
  x = x.lines.to_a if x.is_a? String
  x
end 

data = [
  "hello\nworld",
  [1, 2, 3]
]

data.each do |item|
  p do_stuff item
end
```

Now, with unless:

```
def do_stuff(x)
  unless x.is_a?(Array)
    x = x.lines.to_a
  end
  x
end 

data = [
  "hello\nworld",
  [1, 2, 3],
  ['a', 'b']
]

data.each do |item|
  p do_stuff item
end

--output:--
["hello\n", "world"]
[1, 2, 3]
["a", "b"]
```

But it makes more sense to check for a String object before calling a String method on the object than checking for not an Array.

Comment: I basically did this and got it working. Changed it from unless to an if and check for a String. As of right now it is working. Thanks! I just don't understand why I would have this problem to begin with. Obviously it was an array it wouldn't complain about it being an array on line 2.

Comment: @Jon Heckman, I'll post an example using your unless clause, and you can compare it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `to_a` after `lines`. It is always an array. You can do this:

```
case variablename
when Array then variablename
when String then variablename.lines
else p variablename.class # For debugging. This should not happen.
end
```

---

Looking at your error message with the inspection `#Array:0x000000021382b8`, `variablename` is probably not an `Array`.

Comment: [*"foo\nbar"] will return `["foo\nbar"]` though, not `["foo\n", "bar"]` (assuming Ruby 1.9 or later), so it's not what Jon wants.

Comment: Also this answer in no way explains why Ruby would complain that `variablename` is an object of class Array when the code is inside an `unless variablename.is_a?(Array)` block, which, as far as I can tell, was the actual question. Of course the most likely to that would be that it doesn't and Jon is either misrepresenting his code, the error message and/or the error location to us.

Comment: In that case, I assumed that the OP wanted `["foo\nbar"]`. If not, then the "question" is not clear (Actually, there is no question in the OP's "question").

Comment: I agree that the question is not very clear in general, but since Jon specifically called `lines`, at least the part about him wanting the string (if a string is given) to be split into lines seems clear to me.

Comment: Actually, the question was not clear at all. I added my answer to your second comment.

Comment: @sawa You got that final part of your answer wrong, just try `class MyArr < Array; end; variablename = MyArr.new; variablename.is_a?(Array)` and it will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @TeroTilus You are right. I confused it with `instance_of?`. Sorry. Deleted it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking the type (`is_a? String`) I'd check if the object responds to the method needed for conversion. Assuming that you want to iterate over lines provided either as an array of lines or as a (multi-line) string, something like this would work:

```
def do_stuff(lines)
  lines = lines.each_line if lines.respond_to?(:each_line)
  lines.each do |line|
    # do stuff
  end
end
```